# C++: accessing an array of unknown size by using try/catch

Tags: c++, arrays, exception, try-catch

I was using Java for quite a time and had to move back to C++. I didn't use try/catch in C++ so much before, and now when I work again, I encountered probably a very silly problem.

I have an array of unknown size and want to cout all the numbers that exist in it. However, I do not want to use C++ vectors, which would give me an exact size. What I tried is to have a for loop that is not supposed to end by itself. I want to break it when an exception is thrown, which I would catch and handle the problem. However, it doesn't work and doesn't throw an exception.

Can anyone enlighten me? :) Thank you.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
       try {
           cout << symbols[i] << " ";
       } catch (int ex) {
           cout << "thrown";
           break;
       }
}
```

Comment: *"I do not want to use C++ vectors, which would give me an exact size."* - Why not?

Comment: XY problem. You probably want to iterate over the elements of an array, or find out the length of the array. You do *not* want to use try-catch here (it won't work nayway).

Comment: Ed S. > I want to learn what is the problem here.

Comment: OK, the problem is that an out of bounds acces does not have to result in a C++ exception. In fact, it doesn't even have to result in a signal.

Comment: @decas: If you think about the situation a bit more it becomes obvious that catching the exception wouldn't help you anyway.  Let's say you write (I realize you're reading here, but bear with me) to a location 1 element past the end of that array.  Well, you may have just overwitten a byte or more of some other variable, who knows what.  How could you possibly repair that damage in order to get your program back into a defined state?  You can't, so the only sane thing to do is avoid the situation entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing an array beyond its bounds gives **undefined behavior** not an exception.
An Undefined behavior means that the program ceases to be a valid C++ program and may show any behavior, correct or incorrect but you cannot rely on it to be consistent.
You need to keep track of the size by yourself and loop by using that size or throw an exception as you might want to.

Comment: is there any way to check if there is an entry at a certain index without getting a crash?

Comment: @decas: Yes, you *"keep track of the size by yourself and loop by using that size"*.  That or, you know, write code like you know how to use C++ and use a `vector`.  If it is actually an array and not dynamically allocated then you can use `sizeof`.

Comment: @decas if the array has a size that is fixes at compile time, you can get a handle on that. If it is dynamically allocated, then no.

Comment: no. c arrays have absolutely no bounds checking. This is left the the programmer. You are not even guaranteed that your program will even crash.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behavior means that *anything* may happen.  It certainly does not mean "an exception of the type X will be thrown".  Your program is left in an undefined state.  Even if you could catch it what would you do to fix it?  There's nothing you could possibly do, your program is borked.